# Facebook open graph is not able to load my logged in user's details

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to generate an image using `PHP` `GD library`. That's going fine but there's some problem with Facebook open graph.

Code:

```
<?php include 'testbase.php';
$userid=$userNode['id'];
$imagecontent= 'content="http://abdulghani.me/funquiz/test/savedimages/';
$imagemeta = $imagecontent.$userid.'.jpg" />';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fun Quiz | How will be your 2017?</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1778488125734146"/>
    
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="FunQuiz"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://abdulghani.me/funquiz/how-will-be-your-2017.php" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="How will be your 2017?" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="get to know how your 2017 will be like"/>
    <meta property="og:image" <?php echo "$imagemeta"; ?>

    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="420"/>
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
```

`

I'm trying to load logged in Facebook user ID as image name. I'm using facebook's `PHP` `sdk` for connection to Facebook.

When I view my source code the `og` details for image are being loaded successfully. But not in Facebook's Scraped URL.

You can check both here:

[My site](http://abdulghani.me/funquiz/how-will-be-your-2017.php).

[Facebook **scraper**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fabdulghani.me%2Ffunquiz%2Fhow-will-be-your-2017.php) .

According to my `PHP code` it should load user's ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try and constantly change the OG meta data for the same URL, that is asking for trouble. If you want to share personalized content, then use individual URLs for each piece of content.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's working now! Thanks!